# Behaviors of Elasticsearch routing keys mapped to same shard

Tags: elasticsearch

Let say we have an Elasticsearch query with routing keys [apple, bear, peach]. The routing keys `apple` and `bear` are mapped shard 1 while `peach` is mapped to shard 2. When sent, will there be 2 separate queries sent to shard 1, or will there be a single consolidated query to shard 1 because ES has done optimization internally?

Imagine the query sent to shard 1 matches doc1 and doc2. Will the primary shard receive [doc1, doc2] from shard 1, or [doc1, doc2, doc1, doc2] because separate queries are sent? If it's the latter, will ES filters out the duplicate docs?

I read [the ES docs about routing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-shard-routing.html) but there is no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main purpose of the routing feature is to reduce affect of calling all shard of indices. assume you have an indices with 10 shards on 10 node. when you search against an indices, you are using RAM, CPU and I/O of 10 node. with this feature you only call the shard/node that have your information.

base on example, assume you call `/_search/routing=apple,bear` . Only one search query will be sent to the coordinator node. coordinator node check the which data-node have this route parameter on its shard and just will send one request to that data-node and shard 1. so there will not be a duplicate.

assume you call `/_search/routing=apple,peach`. this is same as above but the coordinator will send request to shard 1 and shard 2. again if you have not duplicate doc in shard 1 and shard 2, there will not be a duplicate response.